# Exporting HTML table data to excel not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a small HTML table which i want to export to excel

- My table has col-span,so when i click on export on excel t exports the data to excel but col-span not exported properly
- my table is exporting like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smdpY.png)

**Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#export").click(function() {
    $("#test").table2excel({
      filename: "test.xls"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="test">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Month</th>
    <th colspan="2">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>50</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>70</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<button id="export" class="btn btn-default commonButton">
  <i class='fas fa-file-export'></i>&nbsp;Export
 </button>
```

How can i export the HTML Table as it is in excel

**I am using `table2excel` j query plugin** i am open to use any other plugin also, which can give me correct result

link of plugin i am using :- https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel

Comment: Chcek you tabel.. TH have 2 column nut tbody have multiple column in one row

Comment: @Ashu yupp.thats what i  am asking for,how can i export my html table with col-span to excel

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugin that you're using?

Comment: @freedomn-m i have added the cdn of that in my HTML, `table2excel` https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel

Comment: Have you considered following the advise of the table2excel author and trying the updated TableExport? https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport

Comment: @freedomn-m i have tried TableExport but same issue was there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below script on top & remove prev one. It is working for me:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/unconditional/jquery-table2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
```

Comment: @viveksingh if answer is useful then mark it as up vote which will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

> paste this code in table2excel

```js
//table2excel.js
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
        var pluginName = "table2excel",
                defaults = {
                exclude: ".noExl",
                    name: "Attendancesheet",

                    filename: "Attendancesheet",
                    fileext: ".xls", 
        };

        // The actual plugin constructor
        function Plugin ( element, options ) {
                this.element = element;
                // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
                // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
                // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
                // future instances of the plugin
                this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
                this._defaults = defaults;
                this._name = pluginName;
                this.init();
        }

        Plugin.prototype = {
            init: function () {
                var e = this;
                e.template = "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>";
                e.template += "<x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions>";
                e.template += "<x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>";
                e.tableRows = "";

                // get contents of table except for exclude
                $(e.element).find("tr").not(this.settings.exclude).each(function (i,o) {
                    e.tableRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
                });
                this.tableToExcel(this.tableRows, this.settings.name, e.settings.sheetName);
            },
            tableToExcel: function (table, name, sheetName) {
                var e = this;
                e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,";
                e.base64 = function (s) {
                    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
                };
                e.format = function (s, c) {
                    return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                        return c[p];
                    });
                };
                sheetName = typeof sheetName === "undefined" ? "Sheet" : sheetName;  
                e.ctx = {
                    worksheet: name || "Attendancesheet",
                    table: table,
                    sheetName: sheetName  
                };
                window.location.href = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(e.template, e.ctx));
            }

        };

        $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
                this.each(function() {
                        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
                        }
                });

                // chain jQuery functions
                return this;
        };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```